# Weird apache2 Not Found (Solves when re-starting)

Tags: apache2

I have a very weird problem. When I reboot my machine (Debian linux) and apache2 loads at startup, virtualhosts do not work and my sites throw a `404 Not Found`.

However, this is solved when I manually run `/etc/init.d/apache restart`. I have spend lots of time over it, with no luck.  The same modules are loaded before and after the restart.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK if the virtualhosts are not loaded it won't give out a `404 Not Found`, instead it will give a `500` error. You can test this by requesting a URL that no virtualhost exists for. If you are getting `404` it means Apache has recognized your virtualhost but can not find the requested file.

Comment: Do you really mean `/etc/init.d/apache` without a 2? I guess no. What happens if you do `service apache2 restart` instead? Does this variant also "solve" the issue?

Comment: Is your config file on a mounted drive ?

Comment: Similar to the fs mounting, I've also seen problems where a service bound to a specific IP that was not yet a local one lost traffic to a  *.*.*.* service.

Comment: Do you possibly have a startup file that conflicts with this? I would restart all your other startup files and see if any cause apache to stop working.

Comment: Check your permissions

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted in the comments section, the scripts in `/etc/init.d` are not the same as those in `/etc/default`.  Many Linux variants now use the `services` damon rather than the old `init.d` methods.  Therefore make sure that the Apache configuration in `/etc/default` is loading the same config file, and referencing the same binary, as that in `/etc/init.d/`.

Try doing:

```
service apache2 restart
```

And seeing if that fixes things.  The expectation is that it wont, therefore showing that you have a mismatch between the `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/default` configurations.

Comment: Your explanation is completely wrong. All that the `service` wrapper does in a traditional `sysvinit` context is clean up environment variables before starting the script. Specifically it does not change what configuration is considered.

Comment: The script in /etc/init.d/ could be from an old install of Apache and it could be referencing both a different binary and different configuration file as both are defined there. I feel, with no other evidence, that this might be a case of a configuration file from /etc/apache.conf vs /etc/apache2/httpd.conf or something similar.

Comment: If the `/etc/init.d` script is from an old install, then the `service` command will invoke it, so it would change precisely nothing in regard of which configuration is used.

Answer (score 0):

404 Not Found is an error alerting you that the requested document does not exist or is not accesible.

I suggest you to check the apache error log and post the information back.

It can be related to configuration file issues: 
If you request , for example, the following address "httX://IPofYourServer/", then Apache will look for a file like "index.html" or "XXXXX.YYY",  and the name and path to look for that file depends on the configuration supplied in httpd.conf or any other included file.

If you provide logs and the URL you are trying to access, people will be in a better position to help you out.